# What are some good metrics for intellectual progress (of all sorts)?

Tags: discoveries, philosophy-of-science

My thinking about this topic is vague, and I'm looking to clarify it.

I'm not sure what "intellectual progress" is or if that's even a useful abstraction, but it seems like it should include things like...

- New inventions
- Formalizations of new mathematics (the invention/discovery of probability theory, for instance)
- Scientific breakthroughs
- The founding of new intellectual domains (originating economics, for instance)
- Improvements in methodological standards (the spread of the scientific method being the obvious example)

I'm looking to do a deep dive into rates of intellectual progress over time.

Comment: I find this an interesting question. There is an analogous measure for technological-industrial progress, namely, how much energy a civilisation uses: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyson_sphere#Origin_of_concept With this, I want to say that this question is justified (not unreasonable). There is also the concept of [technological singularity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technological_singularity), when the rate of progress is infinity. Estimating _rate_ of progress throughout cultures and stages of history as opposed to measuring the state of progress seems to be a good amount harder!

Comment: I don't think "intel. prog." has any useful meaning.